# How to upload or fix avatar in Packgist.org profile

Tags: github, packagist

I'd like to know how to display an avatar in [Packagist](https://packagist.org/).

For example, [my package](https://packagist.org/packages/yidas/yii2-composer-bower-skip) doesn't show my avatar, which I set the GitHub-Packagist API correct  or I can't found any upload panel in Packagist profile.

`Installed GitHub Apps > Services > Packagist: set User as yidas & Token`

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing and just figured it out..

You need to register at https://en.gravatar.com and upload an image. This will be linked to your email address so make sure you use the same one as you use at packagist.org

It can take 5-10 minutes before you'll see your Gravatar on Packagist.org

Comment: It's worked! No wonder the avatar URL on Packagist is using gravatar.com.

Comment: Yeah I think they should at least have mentioned it somewhere but it seems like a big secret ;) Glad I could help you as well!